# How to access dynamic field value in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am adding dynamic field using jquery in form but when i try to fetch value from that dynamic field i don't get any value.

**Javascript/AngularJs**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('demoController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.submitForm = function(){
        console.log($scope.book);
        alert($scope.book);
    }
}]);
function getHidden(){
    var inputHtml = '<input type="text" name="sessionDate" id="sessionDate" ng-model="book.sessionDate" ng-init="1233">';
  $('#addInput').html(inputHtml);
}
```

In above example getHidden() will add dynamic field in form and alert/console.log() will show value of that field.

**html code:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="demoController">
    <form id="demoForm" name="demoForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
        <div id="addInput"></div>
        <input type="text" ng-init="demoModel='hi'" ng-model="book.demoModel" name="demoModel" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="getHidden()">Add Field</a>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

To add new dynamic field click on "Add Field". Type some value in field and then press submit so you will get value of preloaded textbox in console not dynamically added field value.

Please check jsFiddle link for complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/krishna91/b6nk7x4d/47/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be in your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Answer (score 0):

`AngularJS` has its own implementation of the subset of `jQuery` that is called [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). So Don't use `JQuery` and `AngularJs` together. You can implement this with only `AngularJs` like below. Hope it helps you:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("demoController", [
  "$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [
      'text here'
    ];
    $scope.addItem = function() {
      $scope.arr.push('text here');
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
      console.log(1, $scope.arr);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="demoController">
  {{arr}}
  <form id="demoForm" name="demoForm">
    <div id="addInput" ng-repeat="x in arr track by $index">
      <input type="text" ng-model="arr[$index]" />
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add Field</button>
    <button ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```